# How many ways are there to merge two sorted lists where all elements of each list are still in the correct order?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to merge the sorted lists $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(A, B, C, D)$ into a sequence of 8 symbols where all elements of each list
> are still in the correct order? (For example, $AB12C34D$ is such a
> sequence, but $ABDC1234$ is not, only because D and C are out of order.

I used Balls in Bins to solve this question. I suppose __, A, __, B, __, C, __, D, __. I just need to arrange $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ into these four slots. I got $C(4+5-1, 4)=70$, which I don't know if it's right. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer is correct. I would think of it as:

There are $8$ positions in the final merged list, four of which are occupied by letters.  So there are $8\choose 4$ ways to choose positions for the letters. Everything else falls into place in only one possible way, since each sublist must retain its order.